# Overwrite bootstrap class properties

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

We are using bootstrap, want to overwrite one of the bootstrap class properties as shown below. I am using Asp.net MVC.

CSS

```
Boot strap 
Panel-heading 
{ 
 Color : Red  
}    

Application CSS 
Heading 
{ 
Color : Green 
}
```

HTML Page

Link Bootstrap
Link  Application CSS

Issue: Still div color is Red.

Can some help me how overwrite color of boorstrap class without using !.

Comment: What about <div class = "Panel-heading Heading"></div>  ? Seems like the order is causing it to be red.

Comment: we tried that, but no luck.

Comment: What about using the same class name (that should overwrite): Panel-heading 
{ 
 Color : Green  
}

Comment: That also didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when your application is loading you are loading bootstrap file first and then your application css file, which is actually the correct way to load it. 
But according to css rules if you apply two classes on an element having same style then the browser will pick the one which it finds first.
It does not depends on the order in which you have applied it on your element which means

```
<div class = "Panel-heading Heading"></div>
<div class = "Heading Panel-heading"></div>
```

changing this order does not matters, what matters is which css file gets loaded first in the browser.

One way to override it is using !important which is not a good practice.

Also having a class with same name in your application is not an elegant solution as a new developer working on your application can get confused as he would not be expecting the native bootstrap classes to work in a different manner.

The other way out is to increase the specificity of your custom class.

Application CSS

```
div.Panel-Heading.Heading { Color : Green }
```

This will increase the specificity of your class by giving it more  precedence and will override the previous class

You can read more about specificity over here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity